# How to send data of array from java to jsp and set the data to variable in jsp?

Tags: javascript, java, arrays, jsp, parameter-passing

This is JAVA

```
public class Dest_id extends HttpServlet {
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)throws ServletException, IOException {
    String destination = request.getParameter("destination");
    String product = request.getParameter("product");
    String currency = request.getParameter("currency");
    String destQuery = "DESTINATION LIKE '" + destination + "%'";
    String prodQuery = "PRODUCT = '" + product + "'";
    String currQuery = "MOST_INFL_CURRENCY = '" + currency + "'";
    if (destination != null)
        destination = destination.toUpperCase();
    ResultSet rs;
    int bil = 1;
    String destID[] = null;

    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bababa","root","");
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from icx_pricing_desk where " + destQuery.toUpperCase() + " AND " + currQuery + " AND " + prodQuery);
        while (rs.next()) {
            System.out.println(bil + "|" + rs.getString("DESTINATION") + "|" + rs.getString("PRODUCT") + "|" + rs.getString("MOST_INFL_CURRENCY"));

            destID[bil] = rs.getString("DEST_ID");
            bil++;
        }

        con.close();
    } catch(Exception e) { System.out.println(e); } 
response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

out.println(destID);
}
}
```

This is my JSP page

```
<body>
<h1>Pricing Index</h1>
<br>
<div id="main_search">
<form name="m_search" method="GET" action="../../Dest_id" id="m_search">
    <table class="searchTable" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="2" border="0" width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="3" valign="top">Product</td><td rowspan="3" valign="top">:</td>
            <td rowspan="3" valign="top">
                <input type="checkbox" name="product" class="prod_checkbx" value="Bilateral-VC">Bilateral-VC<br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="product" class="prod_checkbx" value="Bilateral Non-VC">Bilateral Non-VC<br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="product" class="prod_checkbx" value="Budget Domestic">Budget Domestic<br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="product" class="prod_checkbx" value="Budget High">Budget High<br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="product" class="prod_checkbx" value="Budget International">Budget International<br>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td valign="top">Destination</td>
            <td valign="top">:</td>
            <td valign="top"><input id="destination" type="text" style="text-transform: uppercase;" name="destination"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td valign="top">Currency</td>
            <td valign="top">:</td>
            <td valign="top">
                <select id="currency" name="currency">
                    <option value="RM">RM</option>
                    <option value="SDR">SDR</option>
                    <option value="USD">USD</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="9" align="center">
                <input type="submit" value="SeArCh" id="search" name="search" class="button orange small" style="cursor:pointer;"/>
            </td>
            <td><a href="#" type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" onclick="document.form1.submit()">lol</a></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">

var form = $('#m_search');
form.submit(function () {
$.ajax({
    type: form.attr('method'),
    url: form.attr('action'),
    data: form.serialize(),
    success: function (data) {
        var result=data;
        //$('#result').attr("value",result);
        $('#result').html(result);
    }
});
return false;
});
</script>
    <div id="search_crit">
        <table class="searchTable" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="2" border="0" width="100%">
    <tr><td></td></tr>
</table>
</div>

<div id="search_result" style="overflow: auto;">
<h2>Floor Price Edit</h2>
<div id="result"></div>
<br />
```

So I want to know how to assign the data from java to JSP page. The data from java is a `primary key` which is I want to use it to display details based on the `PK` in JSP page. Such as:

```
<sql:query var="dest_result" dataSource="${db}">SELECT * from table WHERE DEST_ID = '<div id="result"></div>'</sql:query>

                <c:forEach var="row" items="${dest_result.rows}">
                    <tr bgcolor="#DEB887">
                        <td><c:out value="${row.DEST_ID}"/></td>
                        <td><c:out value="${row.DESTINATION}"/></td>
                        <td><c:out value="${row.PRODUCT}"/></td>
                        <td><c:out value="${row.MOST_INFL_CURRENCY}"/></td>
                    </tr>
                </c:forEach>
```

Well... mostly like this. But if you have better idea please help.

Comment: actually it is coming as a string i guess, try to use JSON and set response as JSON or convert it there in the JAVASCRIPT by JSON.parse("yourResponseData") ;